# KeystoneJS site load in different locale than specified

Tags: javascript, internationalization, locale, keystonejs

I have a site in keystonejs to which I am applying internationalization.
The problem is that when it loads the first time, it does it in English, a different language than the one I have defined by default (Spanish).
I need the site to always load the first time in Spanish, not in English.
I am using the i18n module using cookies, when changing the page or refreshing the site, it comes out in Spanish.
And if you continue browsing it is still in Spanish, when you change to English the same thing happens to any page, it is in English. So the problem is only when entering the site the first time.
I ask that it may be that the first time the module starts without having created the cookie on the site, and when refreshing or changing the page the cookie exists. I think keystone may have been rendered before the cookie is created and accepted by the module.
Here is some example of my code:

```
//** keystone.js**//
/**Language*/
i18n.configure({
    locales: global.config.languages,
    directory: __dirname + '/locales',
    autoReload: true,
    syncFiles: true,
    objectNotation: true,
    cookie: 'locale',
    defaultLocale: 'es-CU',
    retryInDefaultLocale: true,
    register: global
});
i18n.setLocale('es-CU');
```

```
//** routes/index.js **//
/ Add-in i18n support
keystone.pre('routes', i18n.init);
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLanguageSiteStart);//check for the cookie and creates it  and set locale to 'es-cu' if it does not exists

// Common Middleware
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);

//My Middlewares
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initSettings);//starts settings from DB, search for settings in Spanis without any problem, so why the site loads in English???
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLanguages);//load all langs from DB to construct the languages selector in the Pug default view
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initCurrentLanguage);//Starts the current lang, Sp or En depending on the cookie
```

Here is the code from my middleware referring to the language

- i18n is initialized at the beginning of the middleware.js file

```
//Init some things the site requires
exports.initLanguageSiteStart = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.cookies.locale) {
        res.cookie("locale", "es-CU", {httpOnly: true});
        i18n.setLocale('es-CU');
    };
    next();
};

exports.initCurrentLanguage = function (req, res, next) {
    var locals = res.locals;

    keystone.list('Language').model.findOne({lang: locals.lang}).exec(function (err, result) {
        locals.currentLang = result;
        res.cookie("locale", result.lang, {httpOnly: true});
        i18n.setLocale(result.lang);
        next();
    });

};

exports.initLanguages = function (req, res, next) {
    var locals = res.locals;

    keystone.list('Language').model.find().exec(function (err, langs) {
        locals.languages = langs;
        next();
    });

};

exports.initSettings = function (req, res, next) {
    var locals = res.locals;

    keystone.list('Language').model.findOne({lang: locals.lang}).exec(function (err, lang) {
        keystone.list('Settings').model.findOne().where('language').in([lang.id]).exec(function (err, result) {
            locals.settings = result;
            next();
        });
    });
};
```

Any help is appreciated, I only need that the site loads the first time in the default language, Spanish in this case and not in English.
Thanks in advance

#### *****UPDATED*** *###

I tried to change the default locale directly from the module and it doesn't work either:

```
//i18n.js
 // setting defaultLocale
    defaultLocale =
      typeof opt.defaultLocale === 'string' ? opt.defaultLocale : 'es-CU'
```

Comment: Where is `locals.lang` set?

Comment: is set in the initLocals middleware. this is what the code says: ` locals.lang = !req.cookies.locale ? 'es-CU' : req.cookies.locale;`